# How to tell where the symbols are defined when linking C code

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu

I am facing an undefined reference issue with specific symbols in my linkage.

```
error: undefined reference to 'g_queue_pop_nth'
```

I am working on LOP & ARM platforms. We are using the same environment on both platforms. Our ARM build is linking without any issues. But on the LOP platform I am hitting the failure above. I want to check from which library that symbol is being defined on the ARM host. Are there any flags or parameters for GCC to get information about what library provides the definition of this symbol?

Comment: You can check the linker output such as `map` file.

Comment: That particular function is from glib: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.60/glib-Double-ended-Queues.html#g-queue-pop-nth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At linktime you may request the linker to tell you in which input file
(object file, static library member or shared library) it finds the definition
of any symbol and in which files it finds that symbol referred to, using
the linker option [`-trace-symbol=name`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html).

For example:

```
$ cat main.c
extern void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    fputs(__func__,stdout);
}
```

Compile the sources:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c foo.c
```

Make a static library:

```
$ ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o
```

Link a program, requesting symbol traces for `foo` and `fputs`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo -Wl,-trace-symbol=foo,-trace-symbol=fputs
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to foo
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfoo.a(foo.o): definition of foo
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfoo.a(foo.o): reference to fputs
/usr/bin/ld: //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: definition of fputs
```

So `foo` is defined in archive member `foo.o` of `./libfoo.a` and `fputs` is
defined in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Comment: Mike, I can use this option.i can see the output as follows : /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0: definition of g_realloc_n
/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0: definition of g_queue_pop_nth ,  /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 i am looking for the path.. Can i get the absolute path of the library ? because in my current working directory i cant see the folder named '/lib64'.. I am not sure where is this '/lib64' folder .

Comment: @santosh `/lib64` *is* an absolute path. A linux file or directory name that begins with `/` is an absolute path. `/` is the root of your filesystem; so `/lib64` is right
underneath it, just like `/etc`, `/usr`, `/home`, `/bin`, `/lib` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a script on Friday to do almost exactly that.   This script finds both defined and undefined references to a symbol in a given directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
#findsym.sh
PATTERN=${1:-"symbol"}
OBJDUMP=armdir/arm-linux-gnuabi-objdump

for f in $(find . -name "*.so" -o -name "*.[ao]"); do
    ${OBJDUMP} -tT $f 2>/dev/null | grep -q ${PATTERN}  2>/dev/null
    [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 && ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 0 ]] || continue
    echo "FILE: $f"
    ${OBJDUMP} -tT $f | grep  ${PATTERN}
    echo
done
```

Usage:

```
 findsym.sh g_queue_pop_nth
```

You'll have to modify your objdump path, and if you are looking through C++ generated files, you may want to add `-C` to your objdump flags.