# Seeing where symbols are looked up, during gcc linking?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have just seen this post: [How to tell where the symbols are defined when linking C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245241/how-to-tell-where-the-symbols-are-defined-when-linking-c-code) ; and tried to run that approach (that is, I tried to look up via `-Wl,-trace-symbol=foo` during the linking command) on my code, which suffers from undefined reference - but the output is not much different from what is given as an example in that post:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to foo
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfoo.a(foo.o): definition of foo
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfoo.a(foo.o): reference to fputs
/usr/bin/ld: //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: definition of fputs
```

The thing is, I've manually added both -L and -l specifications to my command line, which I expect should pass - but they do not.

So what I am ultimately looking for, is a way to generate a log, that tells me, say:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to foo
/usr/bin/ld: ./libyoo.a(yooA.o): symbol foo looked up, not found
/usr/bin/ld: ./libyoo.a(yooB.o): symbol foo looked up, not found
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfoo.a(foo.o): definition of foo
```

... which, I hope, will make me understand a bit easier, which include and linker flag directories and files end up being scanned.

Is there a way to generate a log like this?

Comment: Just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359700/trace-gcc-linker-linking-process ; there is also `-Wl,--trace` which seems to mentions all library files that are scanned for symbols but doesn't otherwise handle a particular symbol; and there is `-Wl,--cref` which creates a table of all symbols, where they are referenced, and where they are defined (if so), which ended up revealing that some paths that I otherwise expected to work are not taken into account.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect in the second output example. The first output is perfectly clear to me (at least in this example). Can you give your real linker output ?

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumePetitjean - I made that assumption, that during the process of linking, the linker must look a symbol up by looking into multiple (`.a`, `.dll`, `.o` etc) files; so if it doesn't find a symbol in one file, it proceeds to look in the next file. All I'd want, is for the linker process to print, which files has the linker gone through *without* finding the symbol - and that is what is shown in the second example; basically just something I wished was there, so I'm asking if there is something similar.

Comment: OK I get it. Not sure it is very helpful. Why not doing a `grep` on the symbol that is not found ?

Comment: Thanks again, @GuillaumePetitjean - well, in the meantime I did solve my problem, so this is it: it turns out, that `gcc` under MINGW64, by default includes its own version of pthreads; and I was trying to link *different* pthreads; I kept getting errors as if there was a different pthread library linked in, and I was wondering why my -I/-L switches seem to be ignored. So I wanted to see whether they are taken into account *at all* - and of course, in this case, `grep` would have been completely useless: it cannot tell me whether `gcc` ignores me or not.